# What is a proper way to remotely update a folder?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, remote, update

I have made recently 14 Raspberrie Pis 3 Model B with some software on them:

1. Raspbian OS
2. Apache 2
3. Several additional Python packages
4. Several folders with HTML, JS and Python files developed by me.

All these 14 Pis are in another city.

I will need to replace the contents of the folders with my software (number 4 in the list). I see the following possibilities:

1. Make 14 new SD cards by image duplication and send them to the customer to let them replace SD cards in the Pis and hope that it will work fine.
2. Ask the customer to connect Pis to Internet and open 22 ports to me - I will just upload new folders needed to be uploaded.
3. Make some script that the customer will upload and run and the script will download a new files and replace the old ones.

The 3-rd way is not preffered as I will need to let the customer go into SSH which will require some skills for the people there.

Probably I miss some better way? What is a propper way to update the software on remote Raspbian?

Comment: 1) Upload your code to a GitHub repository (or some other online hosting service, like Google Drive) 2) `ssh` into the Pi's, either manually or via a script 3) Use `wget` to download the ZIP of your repository, `unzip` it, and `mv` things around accordingly.

Comment: @user96931 can I do this thing automatically like modern Androids do?

Comment: do you have some sort of hosting on the internet (even a simple web server will do as long as you can update it easily)? Or can you host a server from your LAN?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have a hosting. But I thing that GutHub or similar cloud services, dedicated for such task can do a much better job. Right?

Comment: If done right, then yes

Comment: @JaromandaX I just start to learn how to use Git. So is it possible to make RPi "listening" to a GitHub repo and dowload a new version as I upload one?

Comment: no, it is not possible to do that - you would need to use a cron job to git pull periodically

Comment: @RomanMatveev, for simplicity, I suggest just using `wget` instead of `git`, because if you haven't worked with it before, `git` can be tough to learn and use in a script.

Comment: @user96931, i've got your idea! Is there anything built into Linux to make this easier?

Comment: I don't think so, @RomanMatveev, but you're free to ask if you encounter any problems along the way